# How do I create a dark Google Maps image for Google Glass?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk, google-maps-static-api

I need to create a dark/inverted map image for use on Google Glass, since the standard Google static maps image is too bright when displayed on the screen. How can I customize the map theme to look good on Glass?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Google Static Maps API provides a number of customization options to change the colors of the map features. Here's an example of an activity that loads a dark/inverted static map image and displays it in a full-screen `ImageView` on Glass.

The description of the query parameters used to construct the URL can be found in the [documentation for the Google Maps Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

```java
public class StaticMapActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = StaticMapActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String STATIC_MAP_URL_TEMPLATE =
            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap"
            + "?center=%.5f,%.5f"
            + "&zoom=%d"
            + "&sensor=true"
            + "&size=640x360"
            + "&scale=1"
            + "&style=element:geometry%%7Cinvert_lightness:true"
            + "&style=feature:landscape.natural.terrain%%7Celement:geometry%%7Cvisibility:on"
            + "&style=feature:landscape%%7Celement:geometry.fill%%7Ccolor:0x303030"
            + "&style=feature:poi%%7Celement:geometry.fill%%7Ccolor:0x404040"
            + "&style=feature:poi.park%%7Celement:geometry.fill%%7Ccolor:0x0a330a"
            + "&style=feature:water%%7Celement:geometry%%7Ccolor:0x00003a"
            + "&style=feature:transit%%7Celement:geometry%%7Cvisibility:on%%7Ccolor:0x101010"
            + "&style=feature:road%%7Celement:geometry.stroke%%7Cvisibility:on"
            + "&style=feature:road.local%%7Celement:geometry.fill%%7Ccolor:0x606060"
            + "&style=feature:road.arterial%%7Celement:geometry.fill%%7Ccolor:0x888888";

    /** Formats a Google static maps URL for the specified location and zoom level. */
    private static String makeStaticMapsUrl(double latitude, double longitude, int zoom) {
        return String.format(STATIC_MAP_URL_TEMPLATE, latitude, longitude, zoom);
    }

    private ImageView mMapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView = new ImageView(this);
        setContentView(mMapView);

        loadMap(37.8019, -122.4189, 18);
    }

    /** Load the map asynchronously and populate the ImageView when it's loaded. */
    private void loadMap(double latitude, double longitude, int zoom) {
        String url = makeStaticMapsUrl(latitude, longitude, zoom);
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(urls[0]));
                    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load image", e);
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    mMapView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }.execute(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: When i try to download the map i get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 129 . Any idea? thanks for your code!

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that i need to put a Marker and the api is markers=|LATITUDE,LONGITUDE ...So, any idea for this problem?