# GDK with google map view

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, google-gdk

I tried to implement the google map(android way) into my glass GDK application but It seems like glass does not support that at this moment. Is there anyway I can show a mapview in the gdk application? or do I have to show it through the mirror api map?

P.S
This is what I see when I try to show the map on glass. Any thought?

[image]

Comment: You can use the Google Static Maps API for now, great example at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491222/how-do-i-create-a-dark-google-maps-image-for-google-glass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pardon the reference to documentation, but [read about location on Glass](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/location)

Google Play Services is not available on Google Glass (at least not yet).

Comment: If you would like to request Google Play Services on Glass, I would suggest starring the issue at https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=176

Answer (score 0):

If you need maps, we are testing on google glasses our map API and now is working. Please take a look to:

https://github.com/glob3mobile/g3m

If you need further assistance or have any questions, send us a mail

Thanks!